# show a update success dialog after installlation apk successfully

Tags: android, apk

I have an android app, which basically retrieve the new apk from server and install it afterwards. My Question is how can I show a update successful  dialog after installation is finished.
Normally the android installation shows "App installed" and two buttons. One is "done", another is "open".I would like to show a popup dialog when user clicked the "open". It should only happens after the android app is updated. 
Someone has a idea how to get it .

**Update**

I made a packageReceiver and change the AndroidManifest.xml file like following:

```
public class PackageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        startUpdateSuccessMessageDialog(context);
}

/**
 * 6.0 show the update message 
 * */
void startUpdateSuccessMessageDialog(Context context) {
    AlertDialog.Builder updateBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    updateBuilder.setMessage(R.string.download_success);
    updateBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            return;
        }
    });
    AlertDialog updateDialog = updateBuilder.create();
    updateDialog.show();
}
}
```

And the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".PackageReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The receiver doesn't called after I click "open" in the "App installed" dialog.
can someone help me on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class which extends `BroadcastReceiver`. Because whenever a new app is installed/upgraded, the system sends `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` broadcast.
Receive this broadcast in your receiver and take appropriate action

Comment: that means, when user click the "open" in the "App installed" dialog, the broadcastreceiver will receive a event and meantime in the inReceive method i can put a dialog inside.